# class name as an argument to a function without quotes

Tags: function, arguments

I need to pass as a parameter to the class html element.
as a function of this class is used with quotation marks, but I need to pass an argument without quotes
but I want to do it without the quotes

```
var MyQuery = {
    FindClass : function (className) {
        var div = document.querySelector(className);
        return div;
    }
};
var arr = MyQuery.FindClass('.btn');
var paragraph = MyQuery.FindClass('.paragraph');

// i want to write without quote and dot - var arr = MyQuery.FindClass(btn);

console.log(paragraph);
console.log(arr);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't. Well, except in the obvious way: `var btn = ".btn"; var arr = MyQuery.FindClass(btn);`. Otherwise `btn` is `undefined`, and you are really calling `MyQuery.FindClass(undefined)`.

You can get rid of `.` by adding it in `FindClass`, though.